# PyUSB read multiple frames from bulk transfer with unknown length

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb, pyusb

So I'm relatively new to USB and PyUSB. I am trying to communicate with a bluetooth device using PyUSB. To initialize it, I need to send a command and read back some data from the device. I do this using `dev.write(0x02, msg)` and `ret = dev.read(0x81, 0x07)`. I know the command structure and the format of a successful response. The response should have 7 bytes, but I only get back 2.

There is a reference program for this device that runs on windows only. I have run this and used USBPcap/wireshark to monitor the traffic. From this I can see that after my command is sent, the device responds several times with a 2 byte response, and then eventually with the full 7 byte response. I'm doing the python work on a Raspberry Pi, so I can't monitor the traffic as easily.

I believe the issue is due to the read expecting 7 bytes and then returning the result after the default timeout is reached, without receiving the follow up responses. I can set the bytes to 2 and do multiple readings, but I have no way of knowing if the message had more bytes that I am missing. So, what I'm looking for is a way to check the length of the message in the buffer before requesting the read so I can specify the size.

Also, is there a buffer or anything to clear to make sure I am reading next message coming through. It seems that no matter how many times I run the read command I get the same response back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own issue. After running my code on a full linux machine, capturing the data and comparing it to the wireshark trace I took on the windows application, I realized the length of the read was not the issue. The results were very similar and the windows app was actually requesting 4096 bytes back instead of 2 or 7 and the device was just giving back whatever it had. The problem actually had to do with my Tx message not being in the correct format before it was sent out.